# Meteor find() in publish returns data despite empty selector key

Tags: javascript, mongodb, security, meteor, publish-subscribe

I'm creating and app that will allow people to collaborate, so I've created `groups` that people can be assigned to. On the Server, to minimize client overhead and for security I'm only `publishing` data relevant to their group. My code:

```
Meteor.publish('lists', function() {
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
    return Lists.find({group: user.profile.group});
});
```

I get the user object and filter what is published based on that user's `group`. In practice, there should be a `group` ID in their `profile`. But during testing, I've created users with no `group`. And I've also created `lists` that don't have a `group`.

When I console.log `user.profile.group` for my test-case I see `undefined` as expected. Problem is, my `.find()` query with an undefined selector value is somehow returning all documents that ***don't*** have a `group`. It's like Mongo is telling me "*Well, you didn't give us a defined group, so here's all the lists that don't have a group parameter at all!*"

What am I doing wrong? I would think `.find({selector-key: selector-value})` would only return a cursor if it found data matching the selector key/value?

Comment: did you remove autopublish?

Comment: I did. I delete that right away.

Comment: By the way - even if I had autopublish, I'd expect all the data to be returned. Yet in this case, it's basically returning data that does not match the selector. So it's strange.

Comment: I won't put this as an answer yet, because I can't currently check it myself. However, I wonder if it is the following: If you search for a non-existent user, e.g. with an invalid userId, then `user` is undefined (or whatever "nothing-found" answer Meteor returns). Then you're essentially asking to return all documents with `{group: undefined}`. That could cause Mongo to return documents with no `group` parameter. (Or is that just re-stating your question?)

Comment: I think you may be restating my question, but it's indeed helpful in that what you wrote is what appears to be happening. Because the group value is undefined, it's returning all documents with no group. Why it does that would be great to uncover, but more specifically I'd like to stop it from doing that with some sort of query that says "ONLY if this document HAS a group and it EQUALS this value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guard against the degenerate condition with:

```
Meteor.publish('lists', function() {
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
  if ( user && user.profile && user.profile.group ) return Lists.find({group: user.profile.group});
  this.ready();
});
```

Comment: Nice! Many thanks, Michael. Question, though - why is the guard necessary? Why would Mongo return data that doesn't match the selector in the first place? I'm sure I don't understand it well enough but it seems very strange.

Comment: I'm not clear on what the mongodb rules are for matching against undefined. I agree the behavior you're seeing doesn't make intuitive sense.